# I need some guidance in making a mixed effects model in r

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I wonder if anyone can help me to decide what steps to undertake in making a mixed-effects model in `R`.

My data consists of 5 treatments of which the effects are being measured in 10 consecutive time points. All subjects (20) receive 4 of the 5 possible treatments in a block-randomized fashion. I want to construct a model in `lme4`. How would I go about this?

Comment: https://ase.tufts.edu/bugs/guide/assets/mixed_model_guide.html This is a quick tutorial on how to implement mixed models

Comment: perhaps model<-lmer(outcome ~ (1|subject)+factor(treatment), data=data). This gives you the effect of treatment on outcome while controlling for the repeated measuring of same subjects.